# Carbon PHP add months

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I want add Months from a date.
For example this my date 08/04/2019(D-M-Y)
I use the method addMonth() and I get: 08/05/2019(D-M-Y),
Which means carbon added **exactly plus one to the value of M**.
But in the calendar the date is 06/05/2019 (D-M-Y)...
This is my code:

```
$date = new Carbon('2019-04-08');
$date->addMonth()
```

I want date will be after month like in the calendar.

Comment: Which calendar are you using? Why should adding a month to a date not yield the same day of month?

Answer (score 3):

just chain the methods:

```
$date =  Carbon::parse('2019-04-08')->addMonth()->format('m-d-Y');
```

Comment: Chaining the methods will give the same answer.

Comment: ah, he also mentioned that he wanted to rearrange the format. i guess that's where my thinking lost track. good job on your answer. +1 for noticing the days count

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

The difference between April 8, 2019 to May 6, 2019 is 28 days. Carbon's `addMonth()` adds 1 month to date provided. So, the output it provides is correct.

Sounds like you want to add 4 weeks to the date. For this you can use `addWeeks()` method.